# How to receive a text file from Android to C using TCP/IP Protocol. I am having data loss

Tags: c, sockets, system-calls, tcp

I have already written a code for receiving files from Android to C, but the problem is i am receiving data loss. There is a mismatch of bytes when the received text file is checked with the original text file. How to eradicate this? I have given the code for reference.`

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<unistd.h>
  #include<string.h>    
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<sys/ioctl.h>
  #include<sys/types.h>
  #include<arpa/inet.h>
  #include<sys/socket.h>

  int receive_text(long int new_socket)
  {
      int buffersize = 0, recv_size = 0, size = 0, read_size,     write_size;
      char verify = '1';
      int errno;
      FILE *text;
      char *pBuf;

      //Find the size of the text
      recv(new_socket, (char *)&size, sizeof(int), 0);
      //Send our verification signal
      //send(new_socket, &verify, sizeof(char), 0);
      text = fopen("/home/sosdt009/Desktop/received.txt", "w");

      if (text == NULL)
      {
        puts("Error has occurred. Text file could not be opened \n");
        return -1;
      }

      //Loop while we have not received the entire file yet
      while (recv_size < size)
      { 
         ioctl(new_socket, FIONREAD, &buffersize);
         //We check to see if there is data to be read from the socket 
         if (buffersize > 0)
         {
            pBuf = malloc(buffersize);
            if (!pBuf)
            {
              fprintf(stderr, "Memory Error. Cannot allocate!\n");
              exit(-1);
            }
            //memset(pBuf,0,buffersize);
            read_size = recv(new_socket, pBuf, buffersize, 0);
            if (read_size < 0)
            {
               printf("%s", strerror(errno));
            }
            //Write the currently read data into our text file
            write_size = fwrite(pBuf, 1, buffersize, text);
            free(pBuf);
            printf("%d \n", write_size);
            //Increment the total number of bytes read
            recv_size += write_size;        
            printf(" %d \n", recv_size);
        }           
     }
     fclose(text);
     return 1;
 }

 int main(int argc , char *argv[]) {
    int socket_desc , new_socket, c, read_size, buffer = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char *readin;
    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
      printf("Could not create socket:");
    }
    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 6777 );
    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
       puts("bind failed");
       return 1;
    }
    puts("Bind completed");
    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc,3);
    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if((new_socket = accept(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&client,(socklen_t *)&c)) )
    {
      puts("Connection accepted");
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    close(socket_desc);
    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        perror("Accept Failed");
        return 1;
    }
    while(1)
    {       
      receive_text(new_socket);
    }
    close(socket_desc);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You might like to log the value for `size` as received and verify it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
read_size = recv(new_socket, pBuf, buffersize, 0);
```

`recv()` tells you how much bytess it received for the current iteration, namly `read_size` bytes.

And here

```
write_size = fwrite(pBuf, 1, buffersize, text);
```

you ignore the number of bytes received, but always write `buffersize`.

Fix this by writing to the target file the actual received amount of data:

```
write_size = fwrite(pBuf, 1, read_size, text);
```

---

The call to `recv()` receiving the number of bytes to come fully misses any error checking.

When transfering binary data you also need to make sure not to stumble over

1. possible different widths of an integer value on sender and receiver
2. different Endianness on sender and receiver

To take care of the 1st possible issue above use a well defined data type in terms of bit-width. Here `int32_t` instead of `int` or probably the unsigned pedant: `unint32_t`

For the 2nd possible pitfall tranfer data in network byte order. To achieve this do not send the plain `int` (or `uint32_t`) but convert it to network byte-order (prior to sending it) via a call to `htonl()`. On the receiving side then convert it back to host-byte order using `ntohl()`.

---

The case that the sender closes the socket during transmission is ignored but should be handled by testing the result of `recv()` against `0`, which indicates the closure of the socket by the sender.

---

Also casting `int c` to `socklen_t` on the call to `accept()` is possibly provoking undefined behaviour.

To fix this instead of

```
int c;
```

define

```
socklen_t c;
```

---

Also<sup>2</sup> the code close `socket_desc` twice and does not close `new_socket` at all.

---

Also<sup>3</sup> doing

```
ioctl(new_socket, FIONREAD, &buffersize);
```

to test whether data is available does make sense, as the socket's buffer is filles asynchronously to the program by the kernel, so the value returned by the call to `ioctl()` might be outdated within a wink.

Just remove this call to `ioctl()` and define a fixed-size buffer to read into. `recv()` will block until data is available.

Comment: I have modified the code according to the comments above but still, there is a loss of data.